# How do I get dropdown in controls addon for Storybook?

Tags: storybook

I want to get this:
[image]

My stories.tsx code looks like this:

```
export default {
  title: "Components/Switch",
  argTypes: {
    color: { control: "select", options: ["primary", "secondary"] },
  },
};
```

However, the page just fails to render when I do that.

**To reproduce:**

Clone this repository: https://github.com/jauggy/storybook-args-error

`npm i`

`npm run storybook`

Select the Switch component on the left menu.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you should send an object to the `control` property. Like this:

```js
export default {
  title: "Components/Switch",
  argTypes: {
    color: { control: { type: "select", options: ["primary", "secondary"] } },
  },
};
```

**Update** after Storybook v7 control.options will be deprecated for more info go to: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-controloptions

Comment: Storybook v7: you would move the `options` array as a child of `color` and a sibling of `control`. This also works in Storybook v6.2

Comment: This does not seem to work v6.5

Answer (score 6):

You could also provide there an `enum`:

```js
const SwitchTypeEnum {
    PRIMARY = "primary",
    SECONDARY = "secondary",
}

export default {
  title: "Components/Switch",
  argTypes: {
    table: {
        summary: "SwitchTypeEnum",
        defaultValue: { summary: "SwitchTypeEnum.PRIMARY" },
    },
    color: { control: { type: "select", options: SwitchTypeEnum },
  },
};
```

Comment: do you know if we could connect options directly to  .d.ts (typescript ), ex: if i have a interface of  {   varient?: "primary" | "secondary" | "dark" | "white" }, then making a enums again is i feel lazy

Answer (score 0):

In Storybook 7, like this

```
    propertyB: {
      options: ['Another Item One', 'Another Item Two', 'Another Item Three'],
    },
```

Reference: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#dealing-with-complex-values